# Is there a "ls" replacement that can handle wildcards?

Tags: ls, wildcards, shopt

I just learned that ls cannot handle wildcards (`ls '*'` does not work) and therefore the shell does it before ls is invoked.
So the behaviour of ls may be considered as logically for people working 20 years with unix, for me it is not and I not keep with ls.

I want a directory command that scans for files and directories and *afterwards* applies the wildcard filter. So that a `ls cr*` does not list files inside the directory "cron.daily".

I know that there is `ls -d` and I made an `alias lx=ls -lartd`.
But then I recognized that `ls -d` without any argument for some secret reason does not work at all.

Is there any replacement which I can install?

Comment: you can write your own script to encapsulate the `ls` command and behave the way you want it to, as a solution.

Comment: It's not a secret reason.  It has been on SuperUser at http://superuser.com/a/344896/38062 for four and a half years, and that wasn't exactly revelatory.

Comment: Even if you manage to achieve this, you'll then have a command which handles wildcards completely differently from every other program.   That makes this an incredibly bad idea - ou'll be confusing yourself constantly because you'll be using two similar-seeming but different wildcard implementations.  You would be much better off just putting in the small effort required to a) use shell globbing effectively and b) learn and understand the various options to programs like `ls`.  Unix is not MS-DOS or CMD.EXE....it's also **not hard** to learn basic things like this.

Comment: sorry, but the machine has to do what I want and not vice versa. if it does not, it will be replaced.

Comment: `ls -d` works! It just displays the current directory (`.`), like you asked it to.

Comment: @Kusalananda it was what it was designed to do. It doesn't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `find`, which (on many platforms) has an `-ls` option.  So you could do

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -name '*' -ls
```

But if it is hard to remember `ls -d`, you may not find `find` an improvement.

Comment: find -maxdepth 1 -ls -name '*'  is near to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a command `cmd` so that `cmd cr*` lists `cron.daily` itself, then that command is `ls -d`. If that's too much typing, you can define an [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases). For example, put this line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias l='ls -d'
```

Then running `l cr*` will display information about `cron.daily` itself, while `ls cr*` will list the contents of the directory `cron.daily` (and of any other directory matching the pattern and any other non-directory matching the pattern).

---

`ls -d` does work. It does exactly what you asked it to: it lists the current directory itself. That may not be very useful — `ls -ld` is somewhat useful, but not `ls -d` — but computers do what you tell them to do, they don't read your mind to find out what you wanted.

If what you want is to get the effect of `ls -d`, except that with no arguments you get a listing of the current directory, you can define a function.

```
l () {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    ls -l
  else
    ls -ld "$@"
  fi
}
```

Then `l cr*` lists the files whose name begins with `cr`, even if they're directories. And `l cron.daily` lists `cron.daily` itself, not its contents; you can use `ls cron.daily` or `l cron.daily/*` to list the contents. But `l` lists the files in the current directory.

With the function above, `l -a` will pass the `-d` flag. If you don't want that, you can make the function discard options when determining whether it has file name arguments.

```
l () {
  local a
  a=("$@")
  while [[ $1 = -* ]]; do shift; done
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    ls -l "${a[@]}"
  else
    ls -ld "${a[@]}"
  fi
}
```

---

If what you want is a command `cmd` so that `cmd cron.daily` lists the files in the subdirectory `cron.daily`, but `cmd cd*` lists `cron.daily` itself, then this is impossible in bash. By the time the command is executed, the shell has expanded the wildcards, and the command cannot know whether you used wildcards or not.

This is possible in [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), because in zsh you can disable wildcard expansion for a specific command. Zsh isn't the default shell on most systems, but it's just one package installation away. In zsh, you can define an alias with the [`noglob` prefix](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-noglob):

```
alias l='noglob list_files_or_directory_contents'
```

You'll then need to define that `list_files_or_directory_content` function — your requirement is uncommon, so it probably doesn't exist yet. Here's a function that I think does what you're after: list the contents of directories specified directly, and list the directories themselves if they come from a wildcard expansion.

```
list_files_or_directory_contents () {
  local arg matches
  setopt local_options no_csh_null_glob no_null_glob no_nomatch no_glob_subst no_sh_word_split
  if (($#==0)); then
    # No arguments: list the directory itself
    ls -l
  else
    for arg; do
      matches=($~arg)
      if [[ $#matches -eq 1 && $matches[1] == $arg ]]; then
        # Not a wildcard pattern: list the directory contents if it's a directory
        ls -l -- $arg
      else
        # Wildcard pattern: list the matches themselves, even the ones that are directories
        ls -ld -- $matches
      fi
    done
  fi
}
```

Comment: "ls -d" would do what I want. But "ls -d" without any argument does nothing, so it is useless. "ls" without arguments is asuming "." as the argument. If I could change that so "ls" without argumens would be "ls *" then it would be fine. Or is there a difference between "ls ." and "ls *"?

Comment: @jms `ls .` causes `ls` to list the contents of the current directory (unless the `-d` option is passed). With `ls *`, the shell lists the contents of the current directory and passes the resulting list to `ls`. I edited my answer, is what I added what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. The approach could, I suppose, be applied to as many utilities as you wanted. But I really wouldn't recommend that because it will break your "finger habits" when you move to a new system that you haven't yet tweaked.

```
ls() { [[ 0 == $# ]] && set -- *; /bin/ls -d "$@"; }
```

By extension your alias would then be replaced with this function:

```
lx() { [[ 0 == $# ]] && set -- *; /bin/ls -lartd "$@"; }
```